# Launching Terminal.app in the working directory

Tags: macos, terminal.app

I have set up a script that launches the terminal with this bash command:

```
open script.command
```

`script.command` is a Perl script, and it gets executed just fine. (This may look a little convoluted, but it's the only way I've found to bundle a script with an interactive command line in a regular application created by Platypus.)
The only problem is that the working directory of the script is always my home directory, regardless of where the above command was executed. The same also applies to `open -a Terminal`.

I've tried doing this:

```
open script.command --args "`pwd`"
```

which should technically work (using the argument in a `chdir`), but the argument isn't passed to the perl script (`script.command`).

Does Terminal have any command line options I'm unaware of?

Comment: Are you trying to open Terminal when it isn’t already open or are you trying to issue a command in one terminal window and have it run in a new terminal window?

Comment: The former; the script is executed by a Platypus application, which then opens Terminal (if necessary). This way I can include some resources in the app bundle, plus my client doesn't have to mess about with the command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method you describe doesn't work because the arguments are passed to Terminal (which ignores them) and not the script interpreter of the script.

---

Instead, you can use AppleScript to make Terminal first `cd` into the correct directory and then open the interactive script. Replace the `open script.command` with `osascript launchscript.scpt "$PWD" >/dev/null`.

In AppleScript Editor, create a script with the following contents:

```
on run argv
    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        do script "cd " & quoted form of item 1 of argv & " ; ./script.command"
    end tell
end run
```

Save as `launchscript.scpt` and include as resource in Platypus.

This opens a Terminal window that will first `cd` into the working directory of the main script (the `Contents/Resources` of your Platypus application) and only then executes `script.command`.

Comment: I'm redirecting `stdout` of `osascript` because it'll tell you the tab ID of the Terminal tab created for the command. Rather irritating if you don't use it.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! But since Platypus allows AppleScript as well, I was able to get rid of the `osascript` step (after a bit of trial and error) by making the above script the main script and changing line 4 to this: ``do script "cd \"`dirname " & quoted form of (POSIX path of (path to me)) & "`\"; clear; ./test.command; exit"`` This seems to open 2 Terminal windows, although, unless Terminal is already launched.

Comment: @vbwx You didn't mention whether the interactive script is the only thing you're starting, so my answer provided something for the general case of other scripts also being executed. If that's not the case, you can simplify a bit, true. Although, given the call to `dirname`, it doesn't look like it's simpler ;)

Comment: True, I should've made it clearer what the purpose of this app/script is... I've added an answer for my own specific case, but for the general case your answer is the right one.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out, I've overlooked a technique that's far easier.

The main script doesn't have to be changed:

```
open script.command
```

And the beginning of `script.command` now looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use File::Basename;
chdir(dirname($0));
```

Of course, this only works within the confines of the Perl script, so in more complex cases, the AppleScript solution is the way to go.

Comment: Or `cd "$(dirname "$0")"` (bash) or `Dir.chdir(Dir.getwd)` (Ruby).